# Как создать адаптивниый дизайн в Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

Нужно настройти меню под 2 режима смартфона landscape и portrait, вот примерно что должно получиться.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите как решить проблему

Comment: Совет дилетанта - заготовить оба шаблона, проверять текущий режим дисплея и подгружать и отображать соответствующий шаблон. Почему именно так? Я так и не смог добиться на юнити одинаково качественной отрисовки GUI на разных типах дисплеев.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Есть [официальные доки](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/HOWTO-UIMultiResolution.html), конкретно под [iOS/Android советы](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AndroidMobileAdvanced.html).

Проверяйте `Screen.orientation` и грузите необходимые сцены/префабы в зависимости от текущего режима.

Comment: О, не я один не смог добиться нормального поведения GUI "универсальным кодом" :D

Comment: @test123 ну да, удобно как в том же Android SDK не получится. Может и есть какой-то плагин для этого, не знаю. Вообще, обычно игры строго в одном режиме работают и такой проблемы нет.